# IMEI number formatting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

I'm trying to format IMEI numbers in Excel according to RIM (Blackberry) conventions: XXXXXX.XX.XXXXXX.X

I enter them in excel without any periods and use the "special format" cell properties so it displays right. This works kind of: `######-##-######-#`

However, when I replace the dashes with periods (`######.##.######.#`) Excel automatically changes it to `###.###.###.###.###`, 5 groups of 3. It does this too when I prepend it with a space.

Does anyone know how to disable this behaviour or a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `######"."##"."######"."#`. Works in Excel 2010. Places literal `.`s - anything within quotes is literal rather than whatever special meaning it may hold.

An interesting note, Excel 2010, `######.##.######.#` displays the 15 digit number as `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...` (yes, three literal dots at the end).